# How do I specify two default options for an arara identifier?

Tags: arara

(Apologies if I have the terminology incorrect.)

I want to write a directive for arara that can take an argument.  The directive should set the name of the output file according to the following rules:

1. If no argument is given, use a default value.
2. If the argument is given but has no value, use the `file` variable.
3. If an argument is given, use that.

I thought that the right way to do this would be:

```
command: 'echo @{ name == "" ? "default" : name }'
arguments:
- identifier: name
  flag: '@{value == "" ? file : value }'
```

but I get: `ERROR: Parsing rule '<rulename>' failed.
It might be a malformed directive or orb tag syntax.` if I don't pass an actual argument.

Here's a MWE:

```
!config
# test rule for arara
# author: Andrew Stacey
identifier: echo
name: Echo the value of the argument
command: 'echo @{ name == "" ? "default" : name }'
arguments:
- identifier: name
  flag: '@{value == "" ? file : value }'
```

Then in my test document I try one of:

```
% arara: echo
% arara: echo: {name: 'something'}
% arara: echo: {name: }
% arara: echo: {name: ''}
```

The first two work, the second two don't.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the new `3.x` series, we can easily add a default value to the argument expansion.

Here's the new `echo` rule:

```
!config
# test rule for arara
# author: Andrew Stacey
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: echo
name: Echo the value of the argument
command: <arara> echo @{name}
arguments:
- identifier: name
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( isEmpty( parameters.name ), file, parameters.name ) }
  default: <arara> @{file}
```

New concepts:

- `value` was replaced by a map named `parameters`. If we want to access, say, the `one` directive argument, we simply call `parameters.one` instead of `value` assuming the value in the rule argument context.
- `<arara>` is used at the beginning of the values just to save a few quotes. The expansion mechanism can detect this keyword and safely remove it. You can still use quotes, there's no problem.
- Now a rule argument can have a `default` value, which is the first to be evaluated when the argument is processed. If no `default` is provided, the mechanism sets the value to `''` (empty string).
- We now have several built-in functions in the rule context that might help us write more concise code:

  - `string isTrue(boolean b, string s1, string s2)`: returns `s1` if `b` is `true`, or `s2` otherwise.
  - `boolean isEmpty(string s)`: checks if `s` is empty and returns a `boolean` value: `true` if `s` is empty, `false` otherwise.

It's important to observe that `@{file}` now expands to the filename instead of the basename. If we still want to get the basename, there's also a built-in function for it: `string getBasename(string s)`, `@{ getBasename( file ) }` does that.

Now, let's see the execution:

First rule: if no argument is given, use a default value.

```
% arara: echo
\documentclass{article}
...

  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Echo the value of the argument...

teste.tex
Status: SUCCESS
```

Second rule: if the argument is given but has no value, use the `file` variable.

```
% arara: echo: { name: '' }
\documentclass{article}
...

  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Echo the value of the argument...

teste.tex
Status: SUCCESS
```

Third rule: if an argument is given, use that.

```
% arara: echo: { name: duck }
\documentclass{article}
...

  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Echo the value of the argument...

duck
Status: SUCCESS
```

The comment in the original answer about `% arara: echo: { name: }` still holds. Since `name` has no argument value, the extractor will fail.

---

*Original answer left for historical purposes. It applies to `arara 2.x`*

<sup>How did I miss the [arara](/questions/tagged/arara) tag? `:)`</sup>

Sadly, you encountered an annoyance that went unnoticed during my test suites for releasing the `2.x` series: the only variable available for expansion in the `arguments` context is the `value` itself. So unfortunatelly `file` - and any other variables - won't work and `arara` will raise an error. Hopefully, the upcoming version will solve this issue.

Also in the next release, I have a plan of a default fallback for arguments, so we won't need to write conditionals to check if the value is set. But that's another story, hopefully for the new `3.x` series. `:)`

For now, the only way of making the `echo` rule work is to check the variables in the `command` context:

```
command: 'echo @{ name == "" ? file : name }'
arguments:
- identifier: name
  flag: '@{value}'
```

In the new release, we will be able to write this:

```
command: 'echo @{name}'
arguments:
- identifier: name
  flag: '@{value}'
  default: '@{file}'
```

The directives

```
% arara: echo
% arara: echo: {name: 'something'}
% arara: echo: {name: something}
% arara: echo: {name: ''}
```

should work (the last one *has* to work, unless you found another annoyance). `:)` Now,

```
% arara: echo: {name: }
```

has no argument value, so the extractor will fail.